# Is there a limit size for using pageSizeOptions in Angular?

Tags: angular, material-ui, memory-leaks, angular-material, angular-material2

In my project we are using mat-table to show data, we have pageSizeOptions as 5,10,25,100,250.
Let's say if there are 20000 data to display and if user wants to use 250 as pageSizeOption then after reaching certain page say around 12 or 13th page, in the browser it shows "NOT ENOUGH MEMORY TO OPEN THIS PAGE. Error Code: OUT OF MEMORY.

What is the way to fix this?

I cleared cache and browser history and also tried in incognito mode. If I use 250 as pagesize The issue is seen in 12 or 13th page, if I use 100 as pagesize the issue is still seen but after say more than 20 pages.

Comment: 20000 items are not so much, but you can take approach to "paginate on server" instead of "paginate in client". It's the example "Table retrieving data through HTTP" in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Comment: I just gave 20K as example, the data is more than that.